# Search for occurrences of string in one table field in the field of another

Tags: sql

Let's say I want to find mentions of names listed in one table within another. So for instance I have this table:

```
ID  |  Name
----+-----------------------
1   |  PersonA
2   |  PersonB
3   |  PersonC
4   |  PersonD
```

Now I want to search a field in another table for these persons' names and produce a count for each. Here's what I've tried, to no avail:

```
select 
  Name, 
  sum(
        select
          count(*)
        from Posts
        where Posts.Body like '%[^N]' + [Name] + '%'
  ) as [Count]
from NamesTable
order by Name;
```

I am using Data Explorer here on SE, so whatever syntax will work there is what I need. I'm not sure how to get this working or if this is even the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is very close.  You just don't need the `sum()` in the outer query:

```
select Name, 
       (select count(*)
        from Posts
        where Posts.Body like '%[^N]' + [Name] + '%'
       ) as [Count]
from NamesTable
order by Name;
```